# What is the meaning of the sentence given below?

Tags: grammar

Context:

**Life is tough, my darling, but so are you.**

More specifically, I want to understand the meaning of "but so are you". This is a quote which I read on the internet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *so are you* element in OP's cited context means *you are **also** tough* - that's to say, the construction *X is [adjective], so is Y* is equivalent to *X is [adjective]. Y is also [adjective]*.

The other point to note is that OP's example uses the *contrastive* conjuction ***but***, rather than ***and***. By explicitly contrasting the toughness of the addressee with the toughness of life in general, the speaker implies that she is tough enough to withstand the harsh realities of life.

If he had instead said *Life is tough, my darling, **and** so are you*, this might well carry the implication that he thinks she treats *him* harshly. Effectively, the speaker already perceives his own life as "tough"; he's comparing the way life treats him with the way his "darling" (sweetheart) treats him.