# Is a simple "context" a good start to ask questions?

Tags: word-usage

I've seen lots of people begin their questions with a simple "context", such as ([What is the meaning of the sentence given below?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/152309)), ([What are the differences among the sentences when "make", "cause" and "tend" are used?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/152320)) and so on.

I asked some questions in the similar way. For instance, in post [Why does she have to call her roommate at work?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/240408/109190), I started the question with

> Here is the context ...

The answer to that question reminders me "**a matter of politeness**".

Is it friendly to start questions with just a "context"?

Is there other more polite ways to start questions?

Comment: Do you know about the Meta English Language Learners site?  This is a question about ELL and not about learning a language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I answered the question with the "politeness" answer, I thought I might jump in here too.

I think it is perfectly friendly to start with just the context of your question. However, **do** give as much context as is possible. Starting with the context is important and logical, and is the best way to assist the people who will try to answer a question. There are not really other, more polite ways to start questions in the context of the Stack Exchange website.

This [Code of Conduct](https://english.stackexchange.com/conduct) from the English Language and Usage SE site might help. When you scroll through it, it gives examples of "unfriendly" phrases vs "friendly" ones.

---

To give you specific examples:

One thing especially good in the "Why does she have to call her roommate at work?" question is that you provided a link to the source that your question originally came from. Providing links to what caused a question helps others understand the bigger context around a question. Understanding the bigger context is useful because, when seeing that, the person answering may notice a small aspect that contributed to a person's question.

In general, when asking questions, the best thing is to provide relevant information for the people who will answer the question. For example, a person could ask themself:

"Where is the source of the content that caused my question?"
"What specific part of this source caused me to have this question?"
"What do I already know about my question?"
"Has prior research been helpful?"
"What solutions have i tried so far?"

If you include the answer to any of these questions in the context of a question you post, that will also help. You don't have to include the answer of all of them - a person might not even know the answer to all of them, because their question is very confusing or complicated.

Out Stack Exchange site also has [a page that explains the qualities of good questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).