# see, saw, have seen

Tags: tense

In one of my posts ([Is a simple "context" a good start to ask questions?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/240422/109190)) I said

> **I've seen** lots of people begin their questions with ...

where I used present perfect tense. Actually, I am not sure whether I used the right tense. Other options would present simple, past simple

> **I see** lots of people begin their questions with ...
>
> **I saw** lots of people begin their questions with ...

I was trying to emphasize the fact that there are indeed lots of people begin their questions in that way.

In this context, which tense should I use?

Comment: It can depend on context. For example, this is fine: "I was curious, so I looked at many other questions like this one. I saw lots of people begin their questions with ... ." Here, "I saw" tells about something that happened in the past, when you were looking at questions.

Comment: @DavidK  That context is helpful. Thank you. In which, saw does not imply those past are not there anymore, and I don't know, because I saw them in the past, I don't know their state in the present, right?

Comment: It's simple past because it is part of a story about something you *did* in the past. It doesn't say anything about the present, not even that there is uncertainty. For example, if I say, "Last year the town built a monument designed to last a thousand years," it is past tense not because the monument might not be there any more; it is past tense because *building the monument* is something that *happened* at some time in the *past*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*I have seen* (this happen) means that you have witnessed this in the past.

*I see* (this happen) means that you are still frequently seeing it.

In this context, you can use either according to your personal choice. I wouldn't use *I saw* unless it was no longer happening.

Comment: And what about "I saw"?

Comment: "have seen" also often suggests that it was infrequent.

Comment: I said _I wouldn't use I saw unless it was no longer happening._ "I saw this happen once," or "I saw this in the 1990s but I haven't seen it since."